# Display list items and count occurrences from list

Tags: python

Hi this is my first time posting here so apologies for format etc.

So i am doing a Python programming course at college just now and it's assessment time.

The assessment is to take an already made `logfile.txt` that has iIP addresses in it on separate lines and we have to make a program that analyses and displays the ip addresses and also the count of how many times it appears and then separately the same list but display the most common IP occurrence.

So far I have managed to open the file and split it so it takes the IP addresses and add them to a list and a function that displays the most common IP, however, when I try display the full list of addresses and how many times each one appeared I just cannot get it to work.

I have tried using `collections.Counter` but i keep getting a "non hashable error"

I'm not sure where to go from here as no other way of doing a list is working and taking the IP addresses and manually putting them in a list inside Python is not allowed.

**here is my code so far:**

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
readfile = open(filename, 'r')

def most_frequent(my_list2):
    counter = 0
    num = my_list2 [0]

    for i in my_list2:
        curr_frequency = my_list2.count(i)
        if(curr_frequency> counter):
            counter = curr_frequency
            num = i
    return num

my_list2 = []
for word in readfile:
    my_list2.append(word.split(None)[:1])
#print(my_list)

print("The most common IP Address is:", (most_frequent(my_list2)))
```

***result***

```
The most common IP Address is: ['172.16.17.108']
```

***my_list2***

```
[['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.31.214'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.31.128'], ['172.16.31.214'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.31.128'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.31.128'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.38'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.31.213'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.31.128'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.31.214'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.53'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.31.214'], ['172.16.17.108'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.31.214'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.17.191'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.17.41'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.121.104'], ['172.16.121.171'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.121'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.97'], ['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.31.128'], ['172.16.121.115'], ['172.16.17.56'], ['172.16.121.240'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.226'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.64'], ['172.16.121.35'], ['172.16.121.240']]
```

any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: can you share `my_list2` data

Comment: Do you mean show you the ip addresses from the logfile? sorry i am fairly new to this

Comment: after extaction from file you have save the ip address in `my_list2`, i just want to see it's content

Comment: I have added it to the OP, sorry i don't know why i left it commented out in the first place

Comment: Are you allowed to use `collections.Counter()`?

Comment: yes but i cannot get it to work. I kept getting an error stating the list is not hashable :/

Comment: list is not hashable

Comment: ran it again with collections.Counter and it says "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: Each element appended to my_list2 is a list, because it's `word.split(None)[:1]`.  If you used instead `word.split(None)[0]`, you would append a simple element, a string, instead of a 1-element list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list are not hashable, tuple, string, int are.

you need to change code to get the items as `list of ip adress` ie `[<ip add1>, <ip add2>,...]` not as `list of list of ip address` ie `[[<ip add 1], [<ip add 2>]..]`

ie you need to change `my_list2` from

`[['172.16.121.170'], ['172.16.17.54'], ['172.16.17.108'],...]`

to

`['172.16.121.170', '172.16.17.54', '172.16.17.108',...]`

so changes you need to make

```
my_list2 = []
for word in readfile:
    my_list2.extend(word.split(None)[:1])
```

then you can use `collections.Counter` to get the ip address with there frequency

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
readfile = open(filename, 'r')

def most_frequent(my_list2):
    counter = 0
    num = my_list2 [0]

    for i in my_list2:
        curr_frequency = my_list2.count(i)
        if(curr_frequency> counter):
            counter = curr_frequency
            num = i
    return num

my_list2 = []
for word in readfile:
    my_list2.extend(word.split(None)[:1])
    #print(my_list)

print("The most common IP Address is:", (most_frequent(my_list2)))
```

and `my_list2`

```
['172.16.121.170', '172.16.17.54', '172.16.17.108',...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done very easily with `defaultdict` and an f-string, once you correctly have the IP addresses read in from your file.

```
from collections import defaultdict

ips = ['172.16.121.170', '172.16.17.54', '172.16.17.108',...]
counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for ip in ips:
    counts[ip] += 1

max_occ = max(counts.values())
max_ips = [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == max_occ]

print(f"The most common IP address{'es are' if len(max_ips) > 1 else ' is'}: {', '.join(max_ips)}")
```